# How do I set the environment variables that mongoid.yml wants?

Tags: nginx, passenger, mongoid

My server is nginx using passenger

This is the environment variable I have been trying to set:

```
production:
   database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
```

I've tried setting it in:

```
/root/.bashrc
/etc/profile
```

... and I see it when I run $ env, but Passenger I guess doesn't?

I get the following error:

```
db_name must be a string or symbol
```

If I set database: my_app, then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
```

In your nginx.conf with some .sh script like this

```
#!/bin/sh
export MONGOID_DATABASE=my_app
exec "/usr/bin/ruby" "$@"
```